# Leafet.js how do I highlight an entire layer group with external code

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am trying to highlight an entire layer group using JavaScript from code elsewhere on the page. My group is set up like this:

```
var annexa_building =  new L.Polygon([
        [68.23682, -47.46094],[68.3668, -40.07812]...
  ], {'label': popup_annexa, 'popup': content_annexa}).addTo(map);
var annexb_building =  new L.Polygon([
        [68.82387, -29.729],[69.24837, -22.41211]...
  ], {'label': popup_annexb, 'popup': content_annexb}).addTo(map);

var academics_group = new L.LayerGroup([
    annexa_building,
    annexb_building
]);
```

I tried to find documentation on calling an effect with the group referenced, but couldn't. What I need is to be able to call the highlight code for both layers at the same time, like this:

```
setHighlight(academics_group);
```

I also tried doing something like this (calling individual layers one at a time):

```
<img src="images/1.png" class="img-swap" onclick="setHighlight('annexa_building')" />
```

And this:

```
jQuery(function(){
         $(".img-swap").on('click', function() {
            if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
            setHighlight("annexa_building");

            } else {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");

            }
            $(this).toggleClass("on");

        });
});
```

But it reports back that the layer.setStyle is not a function.

The function setHighlight(layer) does work fine within the map.

```
function setHighlight (layer) {
  if (highlight) {
    unsetHighlight(highlight);
  }
  layer.setStyle(style.highlight);
  highlight = layer;
}
```

An ideas on a solution for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation the [LayerGroup](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup) hasn't the `setStyle()` function. You should use [FeatureGroup](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup) that is an extension of the LayerGroup and has the `setStyle()` function.

Also you should call `.addTo(map)` on the entire group instead of each layer. This way if you add new layers to the group they will be automatically added to the map.